# Select from MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table and I'm trying to retrieve any row which has a number in it

For example this:

```
+----------+--------------+
| Name     | age          | 
+----------+--------------+
| name1    |      21      | 
| name2    |      22      | 
| name3    |      21      |
+----------+--------------+
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'age' = 21;
```

the message I get from the is

```
Empty set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

I'm not to sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: select * from table where age=21;
that is working for me in mySql Query Browser.remove the quotes from age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is `'age'`. You don't need to use quotes near `age`.

```
SELECT * from Table1 where age = 21;
```

[See this SQLFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0d3f/4)

Instead of quotes you can use [Backtick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) (`).
Also, Don't use [Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) as you use in table name.

Comment: Thanks. But with the table name i was just making an example.

Comment: @user1646537 That's fine. I also shown table name as `Table1` in the example. :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't add quotes to your column name use like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE age = 21;
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using 'age' simply use **age** it works

Use this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE age = 21;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select * from person where age = 20;
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d3c32/24